# 404 Not Found error on inserting record to [app].meteor.com

Tags: meteor

I uploaded an app to babble.meteor.com, but when trying to insert a record from the client, I'm getting the following error:

```
Messages.insert({name: "lol", text: "hey there"})
"656bffcf-7046-4cce-b460-5441195680ae"
POST http://babble.meteor.com/sockjs/074/ohxs7fj4/xhr_send 404 (Not Found)
```

The application works fine locally and on my intranet.

Here's the code I have defining `Messages` (runs on both client and server):

```
Messages = new Meteor.Collection("messages")
```

Edit:

The POST seems to be going through now, but when I inspect the server-side database, the records aren't actually being inserted, only updated on the client. So when I refresh the page, I've lost all the messages that were inserted on the client. What's going on?

Edit 2:

Looks like this is only a problem for [app].meteor.com, because I pushed my code to a Heroku app and it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it was an [app].meteor.com problem. Deleting and redeploying the app worked fine.

```
$ meteor deploy --delete [app].meteor.com
$ meteor deploy app.meteor.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you see this POST error on the web developer console? This probably means your server restarted for some reason, and your client had to reconnect. This is not necessarily a problem, reconnections to a new server are rare, but do happen.

However, it might mean there is an error in the server code and your application is crashing. Check your logs with 'meteor logs [app].meteor.com' to inspect for problems.

Comment: Works for me :), beat me to doing a chat app.

Comment: Thanks. I'm facing a different issue now, and I editing the question.